# CamelJdbcColumnNames header missed

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I try to use the jdbc component from camel. I found the documentation here: http://camel.apache.org/jdbc.html.
It works well as the result is available from the database but there is no header in the queued answer called `CamelJdbcColumnNames` as mentioned in the documentation.
All i can see is `CamelJdbcRowCount`. My camel version is 2.15.1.
Do i have to turn a switch to enable this?

Here is an extract of my spring-config.xml:

```
<bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:mydbsid"/>
    <property name="username" value="myuser"/>
    <property name="password" value="mypass"/>
</bean>

<route id="route db">
    <from uri="file://data/inbox" />
    <to uri="jdbc:ds" />
    <to uri="jms:sqlret" />
</route>
```

**EDIT:**
To exclude the jms i added a `Processor`. With this i want to debug the message header. This is a new extract of my spring-config.xml:

```
<bean id="jdbccheck" class="mypackage.JdbcCheck"></bean>
<route id="route db">
    <from uri="file://data/inbox" />
    <to uri="jdbc:ds" />
    <process ref="jdbccheck"/>
    <to uri="jms:sqlret" />
</route>
```

The Processor code:

```
public class JdbcCheck implements Processor {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(JdbcCheck.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        LOG.info(exchange.getIn().getHeaders().toString());
    }
}
```

The log message:

```
{breadcrumbId=ID-chris-HP-50597-1429955241877-0-1, CamelFileAbsolute=false, CamelFileAbsolutePath=C:\daten\chris\source\netbeans\GbLuna\data\inbox2\in.sql, CamelFileContentType=null, CamelFileLastModified=1429953640254, CamelFileLength=36, CamelFileName=in.sql, CamelFileNameConsumed=in.sql, CamelFileNameOnly=in.sql, CamelFileParent=data\inbox2, CamelFilePath=data\inbox2\in.sql, CamelFileRelativePath=in.sql, CamelJdbcRowCount=837}
```

The last var-/value pair is `CamelJdbcRowCount=837` which seems to me that it works somehow. But for further processing i want to deal with the column names. So: how to get `CamelJdbcColumnNames`?

Comment: You only get column names if you do a SQL query that returns a result-set, eg usually a SQL SELECT

Comment: Yes. I do a 'select * from sometable' in an in-message. The body of the message contains that sql. The result is ok (approx. 1000 lines). But - as mentioned - no `CamelJdbcColumnName` attribute

Comment: The JDBC driver is maybe an old driver, you may need to set useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics=false as the Camel JDBC endpoint. Read about this option on the Camel website

Comment: @Claus: thx for your time. I downloaded the ojdbc7.jar from oracle.com and switched from jdk8 to jdk7. No luck with that. The `useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics` option does not change anything. I read this before and discard it because the doc says 'applies when using SQL SELECT using aliases' which i don't need for my first tests. --- I will not yet give up, next i wanna look for the source where the `CamelJdbcColumnNames` is set. Any hint where i can find that? Or any other idea what to try next?

Comment: i am an idiot. i used a too old version for artifactId `camel-jdbc` in my pom.xml. `CamelJdbcColumnNames` is now visible in the log - but not in the jms message header. For that reason i will accept the answer that Claus gave. @Claus: thx for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah okay got it now, its because you send the data to a JMS endpoint. And JMS specification only support a number of data types for JMS headers/properties. And that is usually String, numbers and primitive types.

You can read more about this on the Camel JMS documentation page, and from the JMS spec/javadoc.

The column names header is stores as a header of Java collection type and that is not supported by JMS.

- http://camel.apache.org/jms

If you enable the Camel tracer you should be able to see the header before the message is routed to the JMS endpoint: http://camel.apache.org/tracer

Comment: I edited my question, please read the EDIT: The header is missed before dealing with the jms. I assume i am doing something wrong but can't see what...

Comment: We are productive now. The first problem is that the header `CamelJdbcColumnNames` shows the sql-columns not in the correct order. The `LinkedHashMap` in the ArrayList contains the correct order but in case of an empty return we do not have the correct column order in any place. Is there a solution for that?